# Get parameter not working in Zend Framework 1.12.3

Tags: php, zend-framework, get

i'm new to zend framework and i have i problem getting a GET parameter (zend framework 1.12.3). I though i had to type

```
localhost/controller/parameter/value
```

To make a GET parameter and then in the controller:

```
 $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam( 'id');
 $this->view->id= $id;
```

But i'm getting this server error:

```
GET /localhost/controller/parameter/1 HTTP/1.1" 404 7173
```

What am i missing?

Comment: As said Samy Lstmn must add the action.
Another way is to create a route. But in your case, I think you forget action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would work if ID was part of your url which is not.

To retrieve ID param, your URL should look like : http://domain.com/controller/action/id/12